# iOS simulator netbeans not working

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, netbeans-8

When trying to run an app build in Netbeans the system gets stuck when connecting to the simulator.

this my current configuration:

> OSX El capitan
>
> Netbeans 8.1
>
> Node.js and npm = V4.6.0 LTS
>
> Xcode 8.0
>
> Cordova 6.3.1
>
> this is what the output gives, after build succeeds:
>
> When trying to run an app build in Netbeans the system gets stuck.
>
> this my current configuration: OSX El capitan
>
> Netbeans 8.1
>
> Node.js and npm = V4.6.0 LTS
>
> Xcode 8.0
>
> Cordova 6.3.1
>
> this is what the output gives, after build succeeds:
>
> build-ios-ipa: build-ios: ios-run-device: ios-run-simulator: No
>   matching processes belonging to you were found Result: 1 Usage of
>   '--family' is deprecated in 3.x. Use --devicetypeid instead. Failed to
>   find class DTiPhoneSimulatorSystemRoot at runtime. Result: 1 sim-ios:
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 36 seconds)